# What's the difference between らーめん and らーぬん?

Tags: word-choice

Both #らーめん and #らーぬん hashtags lead me to ramen posts. I'm aware that Ramen is called #らーめん. But what is #らーぬん?

Comment: https://copipe-mangakan.com/archives/2569

Comment: @l'électeur: That's a broken link for me. I'll check later

Comment: That is too bad because that link should answer your question in the manga form.

Comment: Does this work? https://copipe-mangakan.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3-1.png

Comment: The link is working again, I get it (the page and the らーぬん) now.

Answer (score 8):

Legend has it that a long ago, a prankster saw the sign that read 「らーめん」 in front of a tiny restaurant while walking down the street.

"What a boring sign!  Think I'm gonna spice it up a bit.", thought the prankster.  He took his permanent marker out of his North Face backpack and changed the hiragana 「め」 to a 「ぬ」 on the sign.  "らー**ぬ**ん!  Damn, am I creative!", he murmured.

Two days later, the dude decided to go check the sign that he had worked on.  The sign had been re-painted in katakana this time -- 「ラーメン」.  "The owner must have thought that would prevent the same kinda prank from happening again.  Is he kiddin'?", the prankster said to himself, shaking his head.  With a marker, he quickly altered the 「メ」 to a 「ヌ」 this time.
"ラー**ヌ**ン!  That's much better!"

Incredibly, this two-kana-system-cat-and-mouse game lasted over six months until the owner finally decided, in distress, to take the ramen out of the "メヌー" (Pun #1).  Needless to say, this historical incident took place in [Hirakata, Osaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirakata) (Pun #2).

Note: I admit unwillingly that the last paragraph is my own creation, but the rest of the information is all over the internet if you search in Nagoya dialect.

Comment: how to search in Nagoya dialect? :)

Comment: Hirakata って何のシャレか、数日わからんかって、今気づいた・・ **ひら**がなと**かた**かな？